# Criar elementos de xml dentro do activity_controller

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

Eu tenho um programa que possui um dropdown com 3 opções.(Opção 1 tem o valor 1, Opção 2 valor 2 e opção 3 valor 3).

Dependendo da opção selecionada, eu preciso criar TextEdits em baixo desse dropdown. Exemplo: Se eu selecionar a opção 2 do Dropdown, ele cria 2 textedits. É possível fazer algo assim usando apenas código java, sem mecher no arquivo xml??

Comment: sim é possivel,só procurar como criar essas view programaticamente

Comment: Mas a questão é. eu não quero criar a view principal programaticamente, e caso eu fosse criar uma pra usar de sublayout, penso eu que eu teria que criar 3 e abrir conforme o que eu selecionasse o dropdown. por isso eu queria saber se tem como criar apenas elementos xml programaticamente e não inserir toda uma view nova

Comment: mas vc nao vai criar 3 sublayout, vc vai criar apenas o elemento que quer, como um textview, e no java nada de xml, olhe aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12985825/generating-edit-text-programatically-in-android

Comment: Puts vc ta certo! kkkk. matou minha questão. Obrigado!